# How to bypass Target Machine refusing connection on external website - PHP file_get_contents

Tags: php, file-get-contents

```
<?php
$f = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com");
echo htmlspecialchars($f);
?>
```

will output

```
<!doctype html> <html> <head> <title>Example Domain</title> <meta charset="utf-8" /> <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /> <style type="text/css"> body { background-color: #f0f0f2; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; } div { width: 600px; margin: 5em auto; padding: 50px; background-color: #fff; border-radius: 1em; } a:link, a:visited { color: #38488f; text-decoration: none; } @media (max-width: 700px) { body { background-color: #fff; } div { width: auto; margin: 0 auto; border-radius: 0; padding: 1em; } } </style> </head> <body> <div> <h1>Example Domain</h1> <p>This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in documents. You may use this domain in examples without prior coordination or asking for permission.</p> <p><a href="http://www.iana.org/domains/example">More information...</a></p> </div> </body> </html>
```

however if i try to do something like:

```
<?php
$f = file_get_contents("http://www.yahoo.com");
echo htmlspecialchars($f);
?>
```

i will receive an error

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.yahoo.com): failed to open
>   stream: No connection could be made because the target machine
>   actively refused it. in C:\wamp\www\popup.php on line 12

is there anyway to work around this? I would like to get certain html elements within a yahoo page but am struggling to open any yahoo page in this manner

Comment: Is it something you need to get more than once? If not just hand-scrape the source.

Comment: yes i should have mentioned that this is something i will need to get more than once and the contents will more than likely differ from each scrape

Comment: try something other then fgc, curl or sockets maybe?

Answer (score 0):

This works on my machine:

```
$page = fopen( "http://www.yahoo.com", "r" );
while ( ! feof( $page ))
print fgets( $page, 1024 );
fclose( $page );
```

Comment: "Warning: fopen(http://www.yahoo.com): failed to open stream: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. in C:\wamp\www\popup.php on line 12" is there some type of ini setting i have misconfigured? not sure why it works with example.com and not yahoo.com in the example i posted and when modifying yours